# How do I prevent Apache/PHP from showing the environment variables section in phpinfo()?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, environment-variables, php.ini

I need to prevent users from accidentally exposing private data stored in the environment variables with phpinfo(). Is there a way to configure apache or php.ini to disallow sections rendered with phpinfo?

Comment: This is actually the reason a fair few hosts disable `phpinfo();` entirely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The information that `phpinfo()` displays is a bit all or nothing. You can tell `phpinfo()` to limit what information to display but you have to trust your users to call the function correctly:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

You can disable the function entirely using the `disable_functions` directive in your `php.ini` file:

> http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions

For example:

```
disable_functions = phpinfo
```

If you're feeling adventurous you could grab the PHP source, hack out the bits that render the Environment variables, then recompile. For example, in PHP 5.3.6 the relevant code can be found in `/ext/standard/info.c` at around line 950:

```
if (flag & PHP_INFO_ENVIRONMENT) {
  SECTION("Environment");
  php_info_print_table_start();
  php_info_print_table_header(2, "Variable", "Value");
  for (env=environ; env!=NULL && *env !=NULL; env++) {
    tmp1 = estrdup(*env);
    if (!(tmp2=strchr(tmp1,'='))) { /* malformed entry? */
      efree(tmp1);
      continue;
    }
    *tmp2 = 0;
    tmp2++;
    php_info_print_table_row(2, tmp1, tmp2);
    efree(tmp1);
  }
  php_info_print_table_end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call it like this:

`phpinfo(INFO_ALL & ~INFO_ENVIRONMENT);` to remove the "Environment" section.

But it still prints the `PHP Variables` section containing all `$_ENV` values, so
`phpinfo(INFO_ALL & ~INFO_ENVIRONMENT & ~INFO_CONFIGURATION & ~INFO_VARIABLES);`

strips these out, so there is not much left.

The section `Apache Environment` *may* still be visible (if you use Apache), showing some sensitive information.